# Search by multiple criteria or single fail

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I created a criteria object to filter search and I want to be free to combine fields or not.
For example search by serial number
or search by ip adress
or both

```
Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Device.class);

    if (device.getSerialNumber() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()));
    }
    if (device.getIpAdress() != null)
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress()));
    }
```

Here I have a result just if I fill both.
Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add Criterions to your criteria, they are ANDed in SQL. To be able to handle the situation you can add an if clause:

```
if (device.getSerialNumber() != null && device.getSerialNumber().trim().length > 0 
     && device.getIpAddress() != null && device.getIpAddress().trim().length > 0 ) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
              Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()),
              Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress()));
} else if (device.getIpAddress() != null && device.getIpAddress().trim().length > 0 ) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("ipAdress", device.getIpAdress()));
} else if (device.getSerialNumber() != null && device.getSerialNumber().trim().length > 0 ) {
  criteria.add(Restrictions.like("serialNumber", device.getSerialNumber()));
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but there is a problem, for the ipadress it's working fine but for the serial number the filter match with all serial number. However the filter looks like correct

Comment: check your device.getSerialNumber(). If that returns an empty string, you won't be filtering anything

Comment: It is not empty, the issue come from elsewhere. I will check ;) thank you

Comment: I found the problem, when i give just the serial number the ipadress is empty so it is searching the serial number AND all ip adress null !! ^^ Do you have any idea to correct it ?